# Java2D performance issue after using setXORMode(Color c)

Tags: java, performance, java-2d

I am working on a program utilizing Java2D, but performance was not as good as i hoped it to be. I made some measurements and found that it can take something like a millisecond to draw a single line, which seemed insane to me.

I tried to create a simple benchmark application, but performance was surprisingly great (2 orders of magnitude better). So I searched for the discrepancy between my real application and my benchmark application. While I could find and fix some issues (e.g. using strokes can slowdown everything by factor ~10 and using OpenGL hardware acceleration makes it even *worse*), a significant performance loss seems to be related to the setXORMode method and I don't get it:

Here is my benchmark code:

```
public class Main {

final static boolean USE_XOR_MODE = true;
static boolean firstFrame = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1900, 1000);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent drawComponent = new JComponent() {
        private AffineTransform originalTransform;

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            if(USE_XOR_MODE && firstFrame){
                System.out.println("Doing some XOR stuff...");
                g.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
                g.setPaintMode();
                firstFrame=false;
            }

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            long timeStart = System.nanoTime();
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            System.out.println("FillRect: "+(System.nanoTime()-timeStart)/1000+"us");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    ;
    drawComponent.setDoubleBuffered(true);

    frame.add(drawComponent);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

If I run this application, I get the following output:

```
Doing some XOR stuff...
FillRect: 6124us

FillRect: 220us

FillRect: 187us
```

If I set the USE_XOR_MODE constant to false, it looks like this:

```
FillRect: 66us

FillRect: 12us
```

Now let's take a look and try to analyze:

- let's ignore the first draw calls and focus on the last: 187us vs 12us
- if there are more draw calls the measured performance doesn't really change all that much... using the xor mode is more than a magnitude slower than not using the xor mode
- note that in both programs the same code is measured and from my understanding should be executed exactly the same way (since  setPaintMode undos the XORMode)
- I even tried using the Graphics2D.set/getComposite methods to restore the composite the the XORMode destroys and PaintMode is supposed to reset with no success
- also note that the XORMode is only used on the first draw call! So using the XORMode even once messes up performance forever it seems!
- if fillRect is *not* called after setting the XOR mode, i don't see any performance issues

My questions:

- Why is there a decrease in performance after calling setXORMode? Is this a bug?
- Is there a way to (re)set the Graphics object to a state, where you gain back the original performance?

Comment: Comment out `System.out.println("Doing some XOR stuff...");`?

Comment: As i said: "also note that the XORMode is only used on the first draw call! So using the XORMode even once messes up performance forever it seems!" or in other words: The system out has no impact on the _measured_ performance

Comment: Same issue... :( Performance seems permanently broken after using `setXORMode()` on a `JComponent` `Graphics2D` once, even when calling `SetPaintMode()` afterwards.